# Using activity alias does not reflect on app icon

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity-alias

Trying to use activity-alias for using multiple icons for my application. This is my manifest code :

```
<activity
            android:name=".splashscreen.SplashScreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenmain"
            android:targetActivity=".splashscreen.SplashScreen"
            android:label="test"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:enabled="false"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenpinkathon"
            android:targetActivity=".splashscreen.SplashScreen"
            android:label="testpinkathon"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_pink"
            android:enabled="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

And this is my code in the splashscreen activity in oncreate :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.sharesmile.share", "com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenpinkathon"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
...
}
```

now when for testing I change *com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenpinkathon* to *com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenmain* it does not reflect. What seems the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple, I had to set enabled for one alias and disabled for the other.

Like this :

```
 getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName("com.****.8888", "abc.SplashScreenA"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName("com.sharesmile.share", "com.sharesmile.share.splashscreen.SplashScreenmain"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```